# Error When making Shared Object (SO) from C Program Using CC Compiler

Tags: c, aix, cc

I am attempting to compile a simple C program into a .so file using the cc compiler on an AIX system. The program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, world\n");

    return 0;
}
```

First, I created a .o file using the following:

**cc -c -fPIC hello_world.c -o hello_world.o**

This seems to work, but then when I attempt to create the .so file using:

**cc hello_world.o -shared -o hello_world.so**

I get the following errors:

**ld: 0706-012 The -h flag is not recognized.**

**ld: 0706-012 The -a flag is not recognized.**

Can anyone tell me what might be causing these errors?

Comment: Find out what exact compiler you're using and look at its docs. If it is xLC (IBM compiler), the docs are easy to find.

Comment: that `-shared` option looks suspicious. you can use `man cc` to see the documentation.

Comment: Looks like the compiler is treating `-shared` as a sequence of short options: e.g. `-s -h -a -r -e -d` .  Try invoking the linker directly: `ld hello_world.o -shared -o hello_world.so` .

Comment: Ok, it looks like it was the -shared option that was causing the error. When I take it out I no longer get any errors, but it was this option that was telling the compiler to make the shared object. I looked in the documentation as mentioned above and found the -G option, but this still does not appear to create a proper .so file, so the question now is what are the options that I need to use to create the .so file from the .o file?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/xl-c-aix/13.1.0?topic=library-compiling-shared Note: function `main` should not appear in a shared object. Use some other name such as `testfun1`.